# How do I escape double-brackets [[ in-line in org-mode

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode

I need to display some R code in-line that contains double brackets.. e.g., `=x[[1]]=` and  `src_R{x[[1]]}` are evaluated as a link.

How can I escape those double brackets, or otherwise disable the linking using inline code blocks?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can customize the variable `org-activate-links` to resolve this issue.

The default value of `org-activate-links` includes `bracket` to activate double brackets as certain links. If you remove this symbol from `org-activate-links` as below, they won't be displayed as links automatically in org-mode.

```el
(setq org-activate-links '(angle plain radio tag date footnote))
```

Comment: Explicitly deleting the element you don't want would be better than assuming what the remainder of the list should look like: `(setq org-activate-links (delq 'bracket org-activate-links))`

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem whilst inside a .org file. But `[[` in my my in-line R code still get converted into links when I publish to html, etc. How can I fix that whilst keeping my links working? In other words, I want `\src_R{x[[1]]}` to publish as code as intended but still want `[[http://www.google.com][search]]` to get converted into links.